# How to merge two branches with the Mac OS X git client Gity

Tags: git, macos, git-merge

I'm having trouble merging two branches with Gity. When I do a checkout on my alternative branch and click: "Merge into master" nothing seems to happen...

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try checking out the branch you want to merge from and do a 'merge into master'

Comment: @Andrew McGregor, that was actually what I did, I formulated my question incorrectly. Thanks for pointing that out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click on master after having checked-out master, then the option "merge into master" won't merge anything.

If not, according to the [python source](http://github.com/beheadedmyway/gity/blob/master/python/merge.py) called by the XCode, it should mention any error message if the merge were to fail.
Since it does not mention anything, that means the [merge doesn't have to do anything](http://www.eecs.harvard.edu/~cduan/technical/git/git-3.shtml) (like when the `ancestor-commit` equals `merge`)

Remember that to merge a branch '`B`' to `master`, you need to:

- `git checkout master` (which you did)
- `git merge B` (in  other word, merge must be called with '`B`', not '`master`', for '`B`' to be merged to '`master`'): if you are sure [`GTOpMerge.m`](http://github.com/beheadedmyway/gity/blob/master/src/GTOpMerge.m) does that when you are selecting '`merge to master`', then it is a bug.

Comment: You are right, I formulated my question wrong. I'm calling "merge into master" from my alternative branch checkout.

After a while it occurred to me that it was merging after all but the UI just doesn't seem to indicate it.

Once I committed and pushed the master branch to the server it was clear that it had been merged all along.

Thanks for your help:)